# Netty HTTP output to HTML\jsp

Tags: java, netty

I would like to create a beautiful output page for my small Netty application. I have several tables and found not appropriate variant to write HTML code in Java classes as if it was huge servlet. What is the best way to avoid that? As I understand, for web I will need additional features. Should I integrate my Netty HTTP server int Tomcat or other servlet containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try some html template library like FreeMarker, Thymeleaf.

Integration with Tomcat for me is not even a choice. Why not just use tomcat.